# Picker selecteditem property binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a Popup page with a Picker which is bound to a collection of items of a class. I am unable to bind SelectedItem property to a property of the binding context and use it in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler. I obviously made a mistake, please help me find it. Below is my code.

AbilityScore class:

```
public class AbilityScore
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string NameLocalized { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Popup page code behind:

```
public partial class PopUpCreationAbilityScoreBoosts : Popup
{     
    public AbilityScore selectedAbilityScore {get;set;} 
    public PopUpCreationAbilityScoreBoosts(ILocalizationResourceManager LocalizationResourceManager, Character player)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //<some code>        
        
            Picker picker = new Picker();
            
            foreach (AbilityScore score in AbilityScores.List)
            {
                 if (staticBoosts.Contains(score))
                 scores.Remove(score);
            }           
            picker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("NameLocalized");            
            picker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, "selectedAbilityScore");            
            picker.ItemsSource = scores;
            picker.SelectedIndexChanged += PickerAncestryFreeBoost_SelectedIndexChanged;
            StackAncestryFreeBoosts.Children.Add(picker);        
    }

    private void PickerAncestryFreeBoost_SelectedIndexChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label l = new Label();         
        l.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "selectedAbilityScore.NameLocalized");
        StackAncestryFreeBoosts.Children.Add(l);
    }
}
```

I tried to make bindings so that when I change selection of an item in the picker, a label is added which a name property of a selected item. Items are added as picker itemsource correctly, but when I pick an item a label added is empty so I guess the binding that doesn't work it the one which binds SelectedItemProperty to selectedAbilityScore property.

Items are added correctly

[image: Items are added correctly]

But a label is empty

[image: But a label is empty]

Comment: you are not setting a `BindingContext` for the `Label`.  However, using binding in this scenario is not really useful.  You could just as easily set the `Text` property

Comment: @Jason Thx for the reply. I need to be able to retrieve an object, not just text, if i understand you correctly, i can't use text property for that, can I?
Also, I don't set BindingContext explicitly, but for some reason Binding ItemSource to a collection works.  How should i do it? I'm really a newbie in this. Thx.

Comment: just use `myPicker.SelectedItem` to get the object

Comment: @Jason Thank you very much, I really feel shameful and I don't even understand why I didn't do it, it was obvious. Must have overthought it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer, according to Jason's comment:

> Just using `myPicker.SelectedItem` to get the object can fix the question.